react: updating value of controlled input based on change of props
I bet has been answered a million times, but I haven't had luck searching in google. I don't know a concise way to phrase the question.
As learning project, I am trying create a simple html editing tool, that includes a side panel where you can edit different properties of each layout element, like in figma. The problem is that in said panel, the input values do not update when I select a different element.

The values in the target objects are changed well, according to plan, but the problem is that the input values persist when I change from one object to another.
I created a demonstration isolating the problem here https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-question-example-3qlyp5 (also below). Here I can select among the two objects, and correctly alter the 'x' field of said object by editing the input. However, when I select the other object, the input value is not updated to show the value of the new object's field. Only the first selection updates the field value correctly.
I am tempted to remove the input and immediately show it again, as to re-instance it, but that's sub-optimal. Since it's a learning project I better ask.
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

const exampleThings = [
  {
    x: "12px",
    i: 0,
    a: "foo",
  },
  {
    x: "5px",
    i: 1,
    a: "bar",
  },
];

const positionParse = (pos) => {
  const parsed = parseFloat(pos);
  if (isNaN(parsed)) throw new Error("oops");
  return parsed;
};

function PositionEditor({ setPositionDef, positionDef }) {
  const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(positionDef);

  const changed = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
    try {
      positionDef = positionParse(e.target.value);
      setHasError(false);
      setPositionDef(e.target.value);
    } catch (e) {
      setHasError(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={value}
      onChange={changed}
      style={{ borderColor: hasError ? "red" : "unset" }}
    />
  );
}

function ThingSelector({ select, t }) {
  return <button onClick={select}>Select thing {t} </button>;
}

export default function App() {
  const [things, setThings] = useState([...exampleThings]);
  const [selectedThing, setSelectedThing] = useState(undefined);
  const selectThing = (i) => {
    const thingIndex = things.findIndex((thing) => thing.i === i);
    console.log("select thing", thingIndex);
    setSelectedThing(things[thingIndex]);
  };
  const editThingPositionDef = (position) => {
    const selectedThingId = things.findIndex((t) => t.i === selectedThing.i);
    const newThings = [...things];
    const newSelectedThing = {
      ...selectedThing,
      x: position,
    };

    newThings[selectedThingId] = {
      position,
      ...newSelectedThing,
    };
    setThings(newThings);
    setSelectedThing(newSelectedThing);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {things.map((thing) => {
        return (
          <ThingSelector
            select={(e) => selectThing(thing.i)}
            t={thing.a}
            key={thing.i}
          />
        );
      })}

      {selectedThing === undefined ? (
        <p>Select something</p>
      ) : (
        <>
          <p>
            Editing: {selectedThing.a}. My x is {positionParse(selectedThing.x)}
          </p>
          <PositionEditor
            setPositionDef={editThingPositionDef}
            positionDef={selectedThing.x}
          />
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}


chatgpt also told me about the redundant 'position' object property assign on line 69.. oops!

ok! funnily enough, ChatGpt gave me a useful answer!
What I needed is a new useEffect hook - that's why I needed a real project to understand the use of the hooks.
Here the fixed code (the only change is the addition of the useEffect hook)
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const exampleThings = [
  {
    x: "12px",
    i: 0,
    a: "foo",
  },
  {
    x: "5px",
    i: 1,
    a: "bar",
  },
];

const positionParse = (pos) => {
  const parsed = parseFloat(pos);
  if (isNaN(parsed)) throw new Error("oops");
  return parsed;
};

function PositionEditor({ setPositionDef, positionDef }) {
  const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(positionDef);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(positionDef);
  }, [positionDef]);

  const changed = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
    try {
      positionDef = positionParse(e.target.value);
      setHasError(false);
      setPositionDef(e.target.value);
    } catch (e) {
      setHasError(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={value}
      onChange={changed}
      style={{ borderColor: hasError ? "red" : "unset" }}
    />
  );
}

function ThingSelector({ select, t }) {
  return <button onClick={select}>Select thing {t} </button>;
}

export default function App() {
  const [things, setThings] = useState([...exampleThings]);
  const [selectedThing, setSelectedThing] = useState(undefined);
  const selectThing = (i) => {
    const thingIndex = things.findIndex((thing) => thing.i === i);
    console.log("select thing", thingIndex);
    setSelectedThing(things[thingIndex]);
  };
  const editThingPositionDef = (position) => {
    const selectedThingId = things.findIndex((t) => t.i === selectedThing.i);
    const newThings = [...things];
    const newSelectedThing = {
      ...selectedThing,
      x: position,
    };

    newThings[selectedThingId] = {
      position,
      ...newSelectedThing,
    };
    setThings(newThings);
    setSelectedThing(newSelectedThing);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {things.map((thing) => {
        return (
          <ThingSelector
            select={(e) => selectThing(thing.i)}
            t={thing.a}
            key={thing.i}
          />
        );
      })}

      {selectedThing === undefined ? (
        <p>Select something</p>
      ) : (
        <>
          <p>
            Editing: {selectedThing.a}. My x is {positionParse(selectedThing.x)}
          </p>
          <PositionEditor
            setPositionDef={editThingPositionDef}
            positionDef={selectedThing.x}
          />
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}



Dang, I was gonna give you a cryptic answer and let you figure it out lol

hah .. might've been more fun
